# Sort a flat list by parent id with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a JSON list of objects with an id, name and reference to parent id :

```
const myList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "name1",
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "name5",
        parentId: 32
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "name32",
        parentId: 48
    },
    {
        id: 48,
        name: "name48",
        parentId: 1
    }
]
```

I would like to sort that list hierarchically, depending on the parent id :

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "name1",
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        id: 48,
        name: "name48",
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "name32",
        parentId: 48
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "name5",
        parentId: 32
    }
]
```

I'm new in Javascript programming and lodash, and I was wondering if there is an easy way to sort that list with lodash ?

Thank you in advance.
Benj

Comment: Your example result is not sorted at all..  

id: 1, 48, 32, 5  

name: name1, name48, name32, name5  

parentId: null, 1, 48, 32

Comment: Yes it is. 
I want the objects in the list sorted depending on the reference to the parent ID..
"name48" is second because its parent id is 1, "name32" is third because its parent id is 48....

Comment: No it is not. The correct order of items sorted asc by parentId is: null, 1, 32, 48. And in your example it is: null, 1, 48, 32 (not sorted properly)

Comment: I never told it has to be sorted by parentId ASC.
It's a linked list. I needed the next element of my list to be the child of the previous, by the relation nextElement.parentId = previousElement.id.
I found a solution. Thank you.

Comment: You never mentioned it in the question, so the task was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution with lodash. 
Not sure it's the best but it works.

```
var parentId = null;
var sortedList = [];
var byParentsIdsList = _.groupBy(myList, "parentId"); // Create a new array with objects indexed by parentId

while (byParentsIdsList[parentId]) {
    sortedList.push(byParentsIdsList[parentId][0]);
    parentId = byParentsIdsList[parentId][0].id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash's method `sortBy`

```
var sorted = _.sortBy(myList, "parentId");

console.log(sorted); 
/* OUTPUT
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "name1",
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        id: 48,
        name: "name48",
        parentId: 1
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "name5",
        parentId: 32
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "name32",
        parentId: 48
    }
] 
*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L88t09ne/

Comment: I tried this method but the output is not correct :
`1, 48, 5, 32`
the correct output is:
`1, 48, 32, 5`

Answer (score 0):

with vanilla js [[].sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method:

```js
const myList = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "name1",
        parentId: null
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "name5",
        parentId: 32
    },
    {
        id: 32,
        name: "name32",
        parentId: 48
    },
    {
        id: 48,
        name: "name48",
        parentId: 1
    }
];
var arr = myList.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.parentId -b.parentId
});
console.log(arr)
```